Possibility of naturally cut diamonds
Is there a chance that diamonds may naturally occur as any of the geometric shapes in such a way that it is naturally brilliant and cut? Obviously, I am not expecting really sophisticated cuts but maybe an octahedron.

Of course it is, crystals often have facets because of how they form. Raw diamonds are often octahedrons. Just search raw diamonds you will find several in any pic of a dozen or more.
